# How to Copy Data From Databricks hive_metastore in a workspace to in another Databricks Workspace

Tags: databricks, azure-databricks

We have data in a databricks hive_metastore workspace that I would like to copy to another databricks hive_metastore in another workspace. For example, you can see in the image there are a number of databases/tables in following hive_metastore workspace

[image]

I would like to copy the databases/tables to the following databricks hive_metastore workspace:

[image]

Comment: Folks, is this even possible?

Comment: Where the data is stored - on DBFS, or in a storage account? Check location of tables

Comment: Hi @AlexOtt, it's been a while. The data is stored on DBFS. Thanks

Comment: If it’s on dbfs root, then no way to access it from another workspace.